# How do I prevent timing out when coping files to my iPad/iPhone?

Tags: itunes, ios

I've been copying dvd rips to my son's iPad. But quite often it would time out like the device has been unplugged. I get similar error when copying music to my wife's iPhone. And the only solution is to unplug the cable and try again. Using another cable (even brand new ones) doesn't seemed to help. I've encountered the same problem on my Windows desktop/laptor and on my MBPr. So I don't think it's OS related.

Any ideas on how to prevent this? thanks very much

Comment: Sounds to me that your iPad connector is broken.

Comment: Try this on windows: http://www.pcworld.com/article/167663/Fix_the_iTunes_Session_Timeout_Error.html

Comment: it's not the connector. even when I have an ipad3 and was transferring movies to it the **day I got it**, it was also timing out.